# Hide button until two names are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide a button until two specific radiobuttons with two different names are checked. I'm just not sure how to go about this..

HTML

```
<form>
    <!-- First question -->
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="trend1" value="Progressing">
        <input type="radio" name="trend1" value="Regressing">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Good">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Bad">
    </fieldset>

    <button class="next" type="button" name="hideQ1"> 
    <!-- Disable this button until one option on #trend1 and #q1 are checked. -->
    <!-- Not a submit button, if that matters -->

    <!-- Second question -->
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="trend2" value="Progressing">
        <input type="radio" name="trend2" value="Regressing">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="Good">
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="Bad">
    </fieldset>

    <button class="next" type="button" name="hideQ2">
    <!-- Disable this button until one option on #trend2 and #q2 are checked. -->
    <!-- Not a submit button, if that matters -->
</form>
```

I kinda know how to do it over the entire form, but what the button does is that it hides the current question, and shows the next one, so just hiding the button till specific names are checked would be the best way for me to go about it..

Any help/tips are much appreciated.

EDIT:

Hide as in, either disable or hide. Something like that.

EDIT 2:

This is what I've tried, maybe it helps you get an idea of what I want.. All it does however is disabling the next button completely.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button[name="hideQ1"]').attr('disabled');
    if ($('input[name="q1"]').is(':checked')) && ($('input[name="trend1"]').is(':checked')) {
        $('button[name="hideQ1"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please tell everyone that these RB are in different groups. would also be great if we knew which two buttons u want

Comment: @KaminPallaghy Yes, only one button can be clicked out of the input with name="trend1" and only one from name="q1" and so on.. I marked the buttons in the html code with a comment?

Comment: sorry, i do not really know, but is there there a visible property of the button. and does a button being clicked trigger an event (eg run the RadioButton_Num1.clicked code), if so then when either of the buttons are clicked get it to check if the other is clicked, then toggle the visible property of the button

Comment: @KaminPallaghy edited, maybe it'll help u see what II want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like that.

```js
var trend1  = document.getElementsByName('trend1'),
    q1      = document.getElementsByName('q1'),
    button1 = document.getElementsByName('hideQ1')[0],
    trend2  = document.getElementsByName('trend2'),
    q2      = document.getElementsByName('q2'),
    button2 = document.getElementsByName('hideQ2')[0]

function checked(inputArr) {
  return [].some.call(inputArr, function (input) {
    return input.checked
  })
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]'), function (input) {
  input.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (checked(trend1) && checked(q1)) button1.removeAttribute('disabled') 
    if (checked(trend2) && checked(q2)) button2.removeAttribute('disabled') 
  })
})
```

```html
  <form>
      <!-- First question -->
      <fieldset>
          <input type="radio" name="trend1" value="Progressing">
          <input type="radio" name="trend1" value="Regressing">
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Good">
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Bad">
      </fieldset>

  <button class="next" type="button" name="hideQ1" value="next" disabled>Next for q1</button> 
      <!-- Disable this button until one option on #trend1 and #q1 are checked. -->
      <!-- Not a submit button, if that matters -->

      <!-- Second question -->
      <fieldset>
          <input type="radio" name="trend2" value="Progressing">
          <input type="radio" name="trend2" value="Regressing">
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
          <input type="radio" name="q2" value="Good">
          <input type="radio" name="q2" value="Bad">
      </fieldset>

  <button class="next" type="button" name="hideQ2" disabled>Next for q2</button>
      <!-- Disable this button until one option on #trend2 and #q2 are checked. -->
      <!-- Not a submit button, if that matters -->
  </form>
```

Comment: Elegant, easily applicable to the rest of the questions, without disrupting other scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach: on every radio change, run a function that checks if the specific ones are checked, and if so, show the button. Otherwise, hide the button.

That's all there is to it, and it should be pretty easy to translate this into JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same radio name ( Two radio ) if you added question through ajax call.

Then you can use same code for all question.

Here's is my approach bro:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { 
 // Your Code Start   
 
  var isTrend1 = false;
  var isQ1 = false;

  $("input[name='trend1']").on("click", function (e){ 
  isTrend1 =$("input[name='trend1']").is(':checked'); 
  isQ1 =$("input[name='q1']").is(':checked'); 

  if ( isTrend1 && isQ1 ) {   
   $('.hideQ1').css({'display':'block'});
  }
 });

  $("input[name='q1']").on("click", function (e){    
  isTrend1 =$("input[name='trend1']").is(':checked'); 
  isQ1 =$("input[name='q1']").is(':checked'); 
  if ( isTrend1 && isQ1 ) {   
   $('.hideQ1').css({'display':'block'});
  }  
 }); 

  $(".hideQ1").on("click", function (e){    
  $('.hideQ1').css({'display':'none'});  
  $('.question_1').css({'display':'none'});  
  $('.question_2').css({'display':'block'});  
 }); 

  var trend2 = false;
  var isQ2 = false;

  $("input[name='trend2']").on("click", function (e){ 
  isTrend2 =$("input[name='trend2']").is(':checked'); 
  isQ2 =$("input[name='q2']").is(':checked'); 
  if ( isTrend2 && isQ2 ) {   
   $('.hideQ2').css({'display':'block'});
  }
 });

  $("input[name='q2']").on("click", function (e){    
  isTrend2 =$("input[name='trend2']").is(':checked'); 
  isQ2 =$("input[name='q2']").is(':checked'); 
  if ( isTrend2 && isQ2 ) {   
   $('.hideQ2').css({'display':'block'});
  }  
 }); 
 

 // Your Code End  
});
// Document Ready Start
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <!-- First question -->
    <div class="question_1">
     <fieldset>
         <input type="radio" name="trend1" value="Progressing">Progressing Q1
         <input type="radio" name="trend1" value="Regressing">Regressing Q1
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset>
         <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Good">Good Q1
         <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Bad">Bad Q1
     </fieldset>
 </div>

    <button class="next hideQ1" type="button" name="hideQ1" style="display:none;" value="Next">Next Question Q2
    </button> 
    <!-- Disable this button until one option on #trend1 and #q1 are checked. -->
    <!-- Not a submit button, if that matters -->

 <div class="question_2" style="display:none;">
     <!-- Second question -->
     <fieldset>
         <input type="radio" name="trend2" value="Progressing">Progressing Q2
         <input type="radio" name="trend2" value="Regressing">Regressing Q2
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset>
         <input type="radio" name="q2" value="Good">Good Q2
         <input type="radio" name="q2" value="Bad">Bad Q2
     </fieldset>
 </div>
    <button class="next hideQ2" type="button" name="hideQ2" style="display:none;">Next Question Q 3</button>
    <!-- Disable this button until one option on #trend2 and #q2 are checked. -->
    <!-- Not a submit button, if that matters -->
</form>
```

I think this will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this approach

https://jsfiddle.net/q4vvdwc5/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputs = $("input[name^='trend'], input[name^='q']");
    inputs.change(function(){
    selected = [0, 0];
    var self = $(this);
    qnumber = $(this).attr('name').slice(-1);
    inputs.each(function(index, element){
        if ($(element).attr('name').slice(-1) == qnumber && $(element).prop('checked')) {
        selected[qnumber-1] += 1;
        if (selected[qnumber-1] > 1) {
            $(this).closest('fieldset').siblings(".next[class$='after"+qnumber+"']").show();
        }
        console.log(qnumber, selected[qnumber-1]);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I also altered your DOM a bit so it's valid HTML. And added a few classes.